# работа с input type = localdatetime

Tags: input

Имеется форма с input type = localdatetime через которую мне нужно отправить в базу данных дату рождения. Но указывая дату 13.02.1876 выдает ошибку Текст ошибки: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'birthday' at row 1

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исправил. Надеюсь так понятнее.

Comment: В БД как правило вставляют дату в виде yyyy-mm-dd ......... а также вставляют её как строку

Comment: Когда задаётся вопрос - всегда желательно не только приложить текст ошибки, но и сам код, который ипользуется для этих целей

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю с базой данных. И учту замечание по правильности написания вопроса.

Comment: Вопросы можно дополнять, редактировать. И, желательно, в этот тоже добавить всё необходимое, включая код. А текст ошибки чуть более отформатировать (в редакторе текста на сайте такая возможность имеется)

Comment: Так же укажите, какая у вас субд и какой тип поля. Как выглядит sql запрос приводящий к ошибке